# declare value for strong parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

i have problem when i have to declare value for one of parameters in my permit and out of post form values . 
look at my code :

```
class QuoteController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :author, :name, :full => true
  autocomplete :Category, :title, :full => true

  def new
    @quotes = Quote.new
  end

  def create
    @quotes = Quote.new(quotesParams)
      if @quotes.save
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        redirect_to root_url
      end
  end

    private
    def quotesParams
      params.require(:quote).permit(:text,:author_id, :category_id, 
                                   {:send_type => ["web"]}, 
                                   {:user_id => [current_user.id])
    end
end
```

but when i try to save in database `send_type` and `user_id` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code for your controller:

```
class QuoteController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :author, :name, :full => true
  autocomplete :Category, :title, :full => true

  def new
    @quotes = Quote.new
  end

  def create
    @quotes = Quote.new(quotesParams)
    @quotes.send_type = "web"
    @quotes.user_id = current_user.id

    if @quotes.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  private
  def quotesParams
    params.require(:quote).permit(:text, :author_id, :category_id)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Strong parameters is more about the structure of the parameters than the actual parameter values. So things like:

```
{ :send_type => ["web"] }
{ :user_id => [current_user.id] }
```

don't assign default values, they're specifying the structure of nested values in `params`.

I think you should handle your defaults in two places:

1. `send_type` should default to `'web'` inside the model.
2. `user_id` should be required by the model but the controller should set the default (because that's who knows about `current_user`.

Something like this in your controller:

```
def create
  @quotes = Quote.new(quotesParams) { |q| q.user_id = current_user.id }
  #...
end

def quotesParams
  params.require(:quote).permit(:text, :author_id, :category_id, :send_type)
end
```

and your model can default `send_type` to `'web'` if the controller doesn't supply a value.